# stuck on scanf of fgets inside Signal handler function

Tags: c, function, signals, printf, scanf

i program signal handler like this ?

```
sig_quit(int signo)
{
    //char ans[5];
    char ans;

                printf("Are you sure want to exit program ?Y/N \n");
                //while(check){ check = !scanf("%s", ans); }

                //scanf("%c",&ans);
                ans=getchar();
                    //fgets(ans,sizeof(ans),stdin);;
                    printf("ans is : %c",ans);           
                    if(ans=='y' ||  ans=='Y')
                    {                                   
                        printf("Goodbye\n");
                        exit(0);
                        return;
                    }
                    else if(ans!='y')
                    {   

                        printf("why ans is : %c",ans);

                    }   
}
```

ok the default behavior is when you press ctrl+\ the
question ask you "are you sure to exit"?
if the user press 'y' it will exit ,but if the user press anything else other than 'y' -->it will stuck on `scanf` again,but i need to exit the function and return to main after the user press 'n' how ?

**Breifly:** it stucks `@ getchar()` or `scanf()`, again after inserting any char except 'y' ,promting it for new input ,after it stuck if the user insert any new char it will exit the signal handler function back to the `main()`

**Here are the new version of code :**

so this is the code recenlty :

```
volatile sig_atomic_t eflag = 0;
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

      /*Here are some code  ,,,,,, */

        Signal(SIGQUIT, sig_quit);  /* must call waitpid() */
         while (eflag) 
         {
            /* Main loop program code */

            log_msg(SIGQUIT);
         }



 ////// there is code below...
          .
          .
          .

    }
void log_msg(int signum)
{   
    char ans;
    //signal(SIGQUIT,SIG_IGN);  
            printf("Are you sure want to exit program ?Y/N \n");                        
        do  {
                ans=getchar();
                if(ans=='y' ||  ans=='Y')
                {                                   
                    printf("Goodbye\n");
                    exit(0);
                    return;
                }
                if(ans == 'n' || ans == 'N') return;

            }while(1);          
}


void
sig_quit(int signo)
{
    eflag = 1;
    /* Do some handling specific to SIGINT */
    log_msg(SIGQUIT);
}
```

**and still the same problem getchar() blocks again if the user press "n||N",until he press again any char and return to main ().**

Comment: These functions are not legal for use in most signal handlers; you are invoking UB.

Answer (score 2):

Calling most library functions in a signal handler causes undefined behaviour, according to the C standard.

Implementations can offer additional support, but if you interrupt a function that is already doing IO with a handler that also does IO, it will most likely cause unpredictable behaviour.

The 'normal' way to do this is for your signal handler to set a global variable, and place a test in `main` to check for that being set, and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `else` with

```
if(ans == 'n' || ans == 'N') break;
```

**edit**

i do not know if there another good way exist:

```
int main(){  
char ans;  
printf('wanna exit?');  
do {  
ans = getchar();  
if(ans == 'y') exit(0);  
if(ans == 'n') break;  
}  
while(1);  
}
```

Comment: but the break needs loop ,does it need loop to put it ?   myHeader.h:290:34: error: break statement not within loop or switch

Comment: ok if it not safe ,how make this scenario?  if the user press SIGQUIT which is "ctrl+\" confirmation question will appear like any traditional programm ,if the user press 'y' it will exit,but if the user press 'n' the program will back to its normal behavior before the signal occur ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want us to read this code? If so, make it presentable. Otherwise, we're just going to think "ugh! That's a burden to read. Next!"...

Signal handlers return `void`. The type that a function returns should *always* be explicitly declared in C. Since `ans` is meant to store the return value of `getchar()`, it should be an `int`.

```
void sig_quit(int sig) {
    int answer;
    do {
        puts("Are you sure you want to exit?");
        answer = getchar();
    } while (answer >= 0 && strchr("NnYy", answer) == NULL);

    if (strchr("Yy", answer)) { exit(0); }
}
```

What exactly do you mean by "stucks"? It isn't entirely clear, but I think you're referring to the behaviour of scanf and getchar *blocking* execution; When data isn't instantly available to the program, they will wait for data to become available and block execution in the mean time. Have you looked into running a background thread to continue processing while the user inputs data in the main thread?